# how to use a Class to let different activites read data from it?

Tags: java, android, class

everybody. I want know if I can use a Class to store data which input from Activity A, and read the same data from Activity B.
There are some variables in my android program I want to share between all activities in it.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can. It all depends on where you have that class referenced. As a static in the application class is a good start, but highly inefficient.

Comment: If you are using that class to pass data between activies, may I suggest using the Extra bundle that comes with every Intent?

Comment: Guys, why the downvote. this is a Q and A. If the question is too noob for you, just ignore. Don't downvote. Other people can benefit from basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want know if I can use a Class to store data which input from Activity A, and read the same data from Activity B.

Yes but it depends on what you are doing if its a good idea or not.

> There are some variables in my android program I want to share between all activities in it.

If these are simple variables and few then you will probably best using `SharedPreferences`.

If there are a lot of variables then you may want to use a SQLite DB to store and access these variables. Or possibly save them on the filesystem.

Of course you can also use `putExtra()` in your `Intent` to send data but it doesn't sound like this is what you want

To decide what fits you best, read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is to store these variables in some static member of some class, or create a singleton class which can store all this data.

More complex ways would be to user the shared preferences or sqlite db as @codeMagic sugggested.

Another option is to pass the data between the activities when you start them view `intent.putExtra`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

See the mockup class below

```
public class myVariables
{
    public String myVariable1;
    public int myVariable2;
    public boolean myVariable3;

  //it is not advisable to use public methods, but for the sake of proofing that you can use variables
  //this example uses this method. Ideally, you need to set get / set methods.

}
```

Now, anywhere inside you app classes you can call

```
myVariables.myVariable1 = "Hakuna Matata";
```

Then

```
Log.i("tag", myVariables.myVariable1); //this will show "Hakuna Matata"
```